# Negative value in anchor property

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

Chaps, using MarkerClusterer (Google Maps JS API), I'm not able to set a negative value for the position of the text inside the clusterer.
I got a custom cluster icon that requires the text to be at the top-right corner of the clusterer canvas.

Currently, I'm with this: [image]. But the number should be inside the white cirlce on the top-right.

Is it possible? If so, why am I not achieving this (the code follows)?

```
var clusterStyles = [{url: 'imgs/mapa/cluster.png',
                      height: 56,
                      width: 48,
                      textSize: 15,
                      anchor: [0, 32]}];
```

Comment: Edited, adding that current situation preview.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was not completely correct. Why you can't set a negative value? What's the error?

Comment: For me `anchor: [-20, 32]` is working fine :)

Comment: Even typing a negative value, the position remains "the same". Actually it goes back to [0, 0] (in my case, [0, 32]).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue (including the version of the markerClusterer you are using).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this working example. It is working fine. I took your script code and just replaced the url of the image:

```
var clusterStyles = [{
    url: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m1.png',
    height: 56,
    width: 48,
    textSize: 15,
    anchor: [-20, 30]
}];

var options_markerclusterer = {
    gridSize: 20,
    maxZoom: 18,
    zoomOnClick: false,
    styles: clusterStyles
  };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mk06wc0k/

Minus values for the anchor are working good. If it's not working for you you have to show more code.

Comment: Dude, thanks for the effort. Your fiddle/code really works fine, no complaints. But the issue was caused by the version of the MarkerClusterer file. Changed my file to the one you used in your fiddle and ta-dah!

Comment: You can download the latest version from the [project page](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer) and upload it to your project.